# What is the equivalence of optimizer in lmer in R and xtmixed in STATA?

Tags: stata

I was trying to run a multilevel model in R using lmer and my model failed to converge with the default optimizer. Then I used the bobyqa instead of default optimizer and my model converged. Now I need to run the (same) model in STATA and I need some help. Anybody knows how to modify the "optimizer" (not sure if it is called so) in xtmixed in STATA? I read STATA manual and tried all the options but it did not work; my model failed to converge with the default setting (similar to R). Any thoughts or suggestions would be very much appreciated. Thank you!